# One-way SOCK_STREAM

Tags: c++, sockets

We're creating a socket using SOCK_STREAM over AF_UNIX (a local file). We have many processes on the system which are clients, and we are only interested in broadcasting messages to those clients. OS is Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

This all works if the file permissions are 666, however as a security measure we want to change it to 644. However, this causes a permission exception when clients try to connect using the below code:

```
int XyzClient::establish_connection() {
     int fd;

     if ((fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
         throw XyzException(strerror(errno));
     }

     sockaddr_un addr = {};
     addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
     strncpy(addr.sun_path, DEFAULT_SOCKET_PATH, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1);

     if (connect(fd, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
         // connect failed, close fd and throw exception
         close(fd);
         throw XyzException(strerror(errno));
     }

     return fd;
 }
```

Presumably the issue is the above code tries to establish read-write access to the file and which is causing the permission error.

Is it possible to do a one-way SOCK_STREAM such that we can lock down the file to be read-only by everyone except the owner/broadcaster?

Comment: How do you make a streaming socket from a file? Do you mean use local sockets (i.e. `AF_LOCAL`or `AF_UNIX`)? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us. And if you haven't done it before, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Which OS? Socket's aren't part of the standard c++ library?

Comment: What do you mean by "causes a client exception" exactly?

Comment: I've updated the question to be more clear. Let me know if it's still isn't up to standard.

Comment: Sockets are in their very nature two-way. There's no way to make them unidirectional. There's also no way to "broadcast" on a local socket, except to send to each connected client one by one You could use UDP broadcasting for the `127.0.0.1/8` network, but as sockets those are bidirectional. You *could* use named pipes, those are unidirectional, but then you can't broadcast at all. You might want to look into other [inter-process communication methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) as well.

Comment: There is a simple solution for *emulating* unidirectional sockets though: Don't write to it. And if the clients write to the socket, just don't read anything in the server. Sooner or later the buffers on the server and client side will fill up, and the client will get an error trying to write to the socket.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , perhaps I am misunderstanding. But anything a client writes is also sent to all other clients. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes you misunderstand. Local sockets are still peer to peer, not broadcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to make a read-only unix domain socket and enforce this with file permissions. From the relevant man page [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html)

> On Linux, **connecting to a stream socket object requires write permission on that socket**; sending a datagram to a datagram socket **likewise requires write permission on that socket**.  POSIX does not make any statement about the effect of the permissions on a socket file, and on some systems (e.g., older BSDs), the socket permissions are ignored.  Portable programs should not rely on this feature for       security.